# Why v²/2 comes equal to (-k/m)*(x²/2) while doing indefinite integration to express v as a function of x in case of spring-mass system.

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

We know that, using *indefinite integration* over **f'(x)** we can get f(x) whose derivative is **f'(x)**. That's why integration is also called *antiderivative*. But when we do *definite Integration*, we get **∆f(x)** for **∆x**.
But in the above mentioned case, indefinite integration gives an absurd result.

The case is as follows,
 [A body of mass m connected to a spring displaces from its equilibrium position..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DSiF.jpg)

On applying force on the body for a while  the body displaces  to x=x(i.e. position w.r.t. equilibrium position is a certain value x) and at that position it has velocity equals to V. But due to its inertia it moves to further to x=a. Durin this displacement from x to a, the body experiences varying spring force and this causes the body to retardate and at x=a, velocity becomes 'zero'.

According to *Hook's law', **F**(spring force)= **-kx**, where k is the spring constant.
Now using this formula and doing a bit of indefinite integration to express V in terms of x, we get the following equation,
[Expressing V as a function of x in case of spring-mass system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYqpJ.jpg)

Since Velocity can't be imaginary,hence this equation is quite absurd. However applying the upper and lower limits **0** and **V** & **a** and **x** respectively for both sides, we get **V = √{(k/m)*(a²-x²)}, which seems quite correct. But the question is why the equation from where we have derived this one seems to be so 'incorrect' or 'invalid' ?

Comment: You dropped the constant of integration.

Comment: First, it's Hooke. Second, you omitted the all-important constant of integration (which is necessarily positive). Tge method is  not incorrect; you screwed up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v \frac {dv}{dx} = -\frac {k}{m} x\\
\int v\ dv = \int -\frac {k}{m} x\\
\frac 12 v^2 = -\frac 12 \frac {k}{m} x^2 + C\\ 
v^2 = -\frac {k}{m} x^2 + C\\
v = \sqrt {C - \frac {k}{m} x^2}$

Now, what you would normally do...

Since $C$ is an arbitrary constant we can replace $C$ with $\frac {k}{m}C.$ And since C is necessarily positive we can replace $C$ with $\frac {k}{m} C^2$

$\frac {dx}{dt} = \sqrt {\frac {k}{m}C^2 - \frac {k}{m} x^2}\\
\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt {C^2 - x^2}} = \int \sqrt {\frac km}dt\\
\arcsin \frac {x}{C}  = \sqrt {\frac {k}{m}}t + \phi\\
x = C\sin (\sqrt{\frac km} t + \phi)$

$C$ is the maximum amplitude of the oscillation.

Comment: That's great , but I am a bit confused about how you replaced C by C² . Can you elaborate that part ?

Comment: C is an arbitrary constant.  You can to a lot of things to an arbitrary constant and have it still be an arbitrary constant.  It would have been even cleaner to replace $C$ with $\frac {k}{m} C^2.$  Which I think I am going to do!

Comment: @Doug_M Oh! That means you are considering the arbitrary constant to be the square of another arbitrary  constant . But I think it would be more clear if we write C= K² , where K is also an arbitrary constant.

Comment: It is pretty standard stuff in differential equation to just keep carrying the same variable name of the constant as you manipulate it... It is a little bit confusing at first and then it becomes old-hat.